# Significado da palavra "odiosa"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Eu estou lendo sobre a suspensão da nomeação de Lula na *Folha de São Paulo* [aqui](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2016/03/1750987-juiz-suspende-nomeacao-de-lula.shtml), e não entendo o significado da palavra *odiosa* nessa frase:

> "A posse e exercício no cargo podem ensejar intervenção, indevida e **odiosa**, na atividade policial e do Ministério Público e mesmo no exercício do Poder Judiciário pelo senhor Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva", diz o juiz.

Para mim parece um substantivo, o que não tem em wordreference.com [aqui](http://www.wordreference.com/pten/odiosa) ou em outros dicionários (não posso postar mais links porque não tenho a reputação).

Alguém pode me ajudar entender essa palavra, por favor.

Comment: Não é um substantivo, é um adjectivo. Vem do verbo odiar (inglês _to hate_ - detestar, não gostar). Neste caso penso que significa mais vingativa, de vingança (inglês _revenge_, _vindictive_ manner)...

Comment: Então eu não entendo a frase. Tu poderias traduzir a primeira parte para mim?

Comment: "De causar ódio"?

Comment: That sentence roughly means: _"Having and exercising a position in a public office [job] may allow for unwanted and **objectionable** intervention, regarding police activity and Public Law Office, as well as in the exercise of Judicial Powers of Mr. Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva"_, said the judge.

Comment: Bah, perfeito! Muito obrigado, Joum!

Comment: Acredito que seja mais relacionado ao medo, e não o ódio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trata-se de um adjetivo (a qualificar *intervenção*). Significa *reprovável*, mas é um pouco mais forte. [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/odioso):

> 1. Que desperta ódio (mulher odiosa): *"Ora sentia-se odioso, ora ridículo. Quem se sente odioso pode ter no orgulho um refúgio..."* (Machado de Assis, Dom Casmurro))
> 2. Que é repelente, insuportável, desagradável (filme odioso); DESPREZÍVEL; REPULSIVO
> 3. Que demonstra ódio (*discurso odioso*); ODIENTO
> 4. **Que é digno de condenação; REPROVÁVEL**

Comment: Resposta perfeita! +1!

Comment: Obrigado, Artefacto! Agora a frase fez sentido para mim.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil, quando dizemos que uma pessoa é "odiosa", não significa apenas que ela possa odiar muitos - pode ser, sim - mas associamos mais a pessoas que nós odiamos, e não a quem nos odeiam.
Por exemplo, se eu disser que minha vizinha é "odiosa", estou dizendo que é alguém que não há como gostar. Ela é tão odiosa que ninguém gosta dela, não há como.